# How to reinstall ubuntu

Tags: boot

I got a new computer (Dell inspiron 3000 series) was a system of Ubuntu I turned it on Windows 7 . I want to have again the old system what to do. ?

Comment: Have you tried googling it and following the instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu is pretty easy if you know what you are doing.First use a USB.After that turn off Secure Boot as that makes the ISO unbootable.Then burn the Ubuntu ISO to the USB using a program like Rufus(Don't use **UNETBOOTIN** it's broken).Then restart your computer and access the BIOS.In there select your USB device.After that you should see the Ubuntu install screen and you should be able to install Ubuntu.